# Display flex, make image same height with another columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height

Here is how my layout looks like. Two columns with an image on the left and 2 rows on the right. I'm using `CSS flex` to form this layout, and there is a tabbing function inside my code.

I wanna make the these two column having the same height but failed. Hoping that some of you could provide me with some advice. Thanks!
[image]

```js
$('#tabs').tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {}
});
```

```css
#Contact, #contact-panel{ height: 92%;}
.fullwidth_contact{
  display: flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -moz-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  height: 92%;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

.rowdisplay_contact {
  display: flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  height: 90%;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}


.repeat-xcontact {
  flex: 1;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.width70{flex-basis: 70%;}
.width30{flex-basis: 30%;}

.country_box{ 
 font-size: 25px;
 line-height: 1.2em;
 padding: 12% 10%;
 background-color: #5ba4ee;
}

.address_box{
 padding: 12% 10%;
 background-color: #ccc;
}

.map { background-image: url("http://geology.com/world/world-map.gif");}

ul.tabs{
 margin:0;
 padding: 16% 0 0 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul.tabs li{
 padding: 5px 0;
}

ul.tabs li a{
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
}

ul.tabs li a:hover, .ui-state-active{
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #1d70c4;
 outline:none;
}

.ui-state-active a,
.ui-state-active a:link,
.ui-state-active a:visited {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #1d70c4;
 text-decoration: none;
}

ul.tabs li a:focus {
    outline:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="tabs" class="fullwidth_contact">
  <div class="repeat-xcontact map width70"></div>
  
  <div class="repeat-xcontact width30">
 <div class="rowdisplay_contact width100">
   <div class="repeat-xcontact country_box">
  <div class="txt8">CONTACT</div><br/>
  <ul class="tabs" data-persist="true">
   <li><a href="#view1">Content 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#view2">Content 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#view3">Content 3</a></li>
  </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="repeat-xcontact address_box">
  <div id="view1">
   <p class="country_title">Content 1</p>
   <p>Cras dignissim lectus sed dui ullamcorper, et suscipit justo vehicula.</p>
   <p>T &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>F &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>E &nbsp;&nbsp; <script language="JavaScript"><!--
   var name = "info";
   var domain = "test.com";
   document.write('<a href=\"mailto:' + name + '@' + domain + '\">');
   document.write(name + '@' + domain + '</a>');
   // --><!--</script></p>
  </div>
  <div id="view2">
   <p class="country_title">Content 2</p>
   <p>Cras dignissim lectus sed dui ullamcorper, et suscipit justo vehicula.</p>
   <p>T &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>F &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>E &nbsp;&nbsp; <script language="JavaScript"><!--
   var name = "info";
   var domain = "test.com";
   document.write('<a href=\"mailto:' + name + '@' + domain + '\">');
   document.write(name + '@' + domain + '</a>');
   // --><!--</script></p>
  </div>
  <div id="view3">
   <p class="country_title">Content 3</p>
   <p>Cras dignissim lectus sed dui ullamcorper, et suscipit justo vehicula.</p>
   <p>T &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>F &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>E &nbsp;&nbsp; <script language="JavaScript"><!--
   var name = "info";
   var domain = "test.com";
   document.write('<a href=\"mailto:' + name + '@' + domain + '\">');
   document.write(name + '@' + domain + '</a>');
   // --><!--</script></p>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the desired result just by commenting out the `.rowdisplay_contact width100` *div* which you, if you ask me, don't even need. I also added some basic *CSS* browser reset which is always good to have:

```js
$('#tabs').tabs({
  activate: function (event, ui){}
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box}

#Contact, #contact-panel{height: 92%}

.fullwidth_contact {
  display: flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -moz-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  height: 92%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.rowdisplay_contact {
  display: flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  height: 90%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.repeat-xcontact {
  flex: 1;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.width70 {flex-basis: 70%}
.width30 {flex-basis: 30%}

.country_box { 
 font-size: 25px;
 line-height: 1.2em;
 padding: 12% 10%;
 background-color: #5ba4ee;
}

.address_box {
 padding: 12% 10%;
 background-color: #ccc;
}

.map {background-image: url("http://geology.com/world/world-map.gif")}

ul.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 16% 0 0 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul.tabs li {
 padding: 5px 0;
}

ul.tabs li a {
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
}

ul.tabs li a:hover, .ui-state-active {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #1d70c4;
 outline:none;
}

.ui-state-active a,
.ui-state-active a:link,
.ui-state-active a:visited {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #1d70c4;
 text-decoration: none;
}

ul.tabs li a:focus {
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="tabs" class="fullwidth_contact">
  <div class="repeat-xcontact map width70"></div>
  
  <div class="repeat-xcontact width30">
 <!-- <div class="rowdisplay_contact width100"> -->
   <div class="repeat-xcontact country_box">
  <div class="txt8">CONTACT</div><br/>
  <ul class="tabs" data-persist="true">
   <li><a href="#view1">Content 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#view2">Content 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#view3">Content 3</a></li>
  </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="repeat-xcontact address_box">
  <div id="view1">
   <p class="country_title">Content 1</p>
   <p>Cras dignissim lectus sed dui ullamcorper, et suscipit justo vehicula.</p>
   <p>T &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>F &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>E &nbsp;&nbsp; <script language="JavaScript"><!--
   var name = "info";
   var domain = "test.com";
   document.write('<a href=\"mailto:' + name + '@' + domain + '\">');
   document.write(name + '@' + domain + '</a>');
   // --><!--</script></p>
  </div>
  <div id="view2">
   <p class="country_title">Content 2</p>
   <p>Cras dignissim lectus sed dui ullamcorper, et suscipit justo vehicula.</p>
   <p>T &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>F &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>E &nbsp;&nbsp; <script language="JavaScript"><!--
   var name = "info";
   var domain = "test.com";
   document.write('<a href=\"mailto:' + name + '@' + domain + '\">');
   document.write(name + '@' + domain + '</a>');
   // --><!--</script></p>
  </div>
  <div id="view3">
   <p class="country_title">Content 3</p>
   <p>Cras dignissim lectus sed dui ullamcorper, et suscipit justo vehicula.</p>
   <p>T &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>F &nbsp;&nbsp; 1234 5678</p>
   <p>E &nbsp;&nbsp; <script language="JavaScript"><!--
   var name = "info";
   var domain = "test.com";
   document.write('<a href=\"mailto:' + name + '@' + domain + '\">');
   document.write(name + '@' + domain + '</a>');
   // --><!--</script></p>
  </div>
   </div>
 <!-- </div> -->
  </div>
</div>
```